# A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again. I have this error and exception in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/timbuchalka/Main has been compiled by a more recent
version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions
up to 52.0

Comment: You used Java 11 to compile the project (or library), but you are trying to execute it on Java 8. Can you show us the 1. `project structure ->project->project sdk` settings and 2. `settings ->build, execution, deployment -> compiler -> Java compiler` settings?

Comment: You can also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi), which might or might not be the answer to your question, depending on whether it is an issue within your IDE config or with your java installation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the application with the JDK not lower than JDK 11 version. Because you have compiled it by the 11 Java language level. Check your Run/Debug Configuration - that you have the JDK 11 set there which will be used to run:
[image]